# Curve fitting in Time series and creation of heatmap uncertainty

Tags: r, time-series

I have an univariate time series with daily values of temperature over 60 years with missing values. The size of the gaps varies from a day to a couple of years. My goal is:

- to impute the missing values
- to estimate the uncertainty at each day to generate an heatmap (x-axis: days and y-axis: year).

My first thought is to fit a curve going through all the points and then calculate the absolute difference between the true value and the predicted value at each day. I am conscious that I won't have any uncertainty estimation when a value is missing.

Is my approach correct?
If yes, how can I do this?
If no, do you have any better ideas?

Note:

- There is definitely a trend and seasonal effect in the time series
- I am ready to assume stationarity
- I am coding in R

Comment: Facebook Prophet does all of that, and also doesn't require stationarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Arima combined with kalman smoothing. Below is the code implemented in R:

```
#Install and load imputeTS package
install.packages("imputeTS")
library(imputeTS)

#Create a time series
myts <- AirPassengers

#Plot the time series
plot(myts)

#Create missing values
missing_index <- c(30:50, 70:80, 120:130)
myts[missing_index] <- NA

#Fit arima model combined with Kalman smoothing
imp <- na.kalman(myts, model = "auto.arima", smooth = TRUE)

#Plot the imputed part
imp[setdiff(seq(1,length(myts)), missing_index)] <- NA    
lines(imp, col = "blue")
```

There is a very nice paper which describes diverse techniques of imputations for univariate time series available here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03924.pdf

For more details regarding forecasting or imputations, I would recommend this book: https://robjhyndman.com/uwafiles/fpp-notes.pdf